# Input Form in Swing GUI is run after main

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, invoke

In SWING GUI i have the methods related to the GUI and a main. I have 2 classes Filename and Result which have the goal to store or read data (their values are static) from GUI to main and from main to GUI.
While the result is properly displayed in the GUI, as it happens in the end, the input is asked before the output but already after all the main has executed.
I want it to happen before the stuff that happens inside main, not in the end.

Maybe it's related to the `invokeLater`?
main

```
/* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            new IOform().setVisible(true);
            //main stuff
    });
}
```

in the main happens all the stuff which should happen between input and output

GUI jButton1 :  (input)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // input (gets executed after the main)
    String a = jTextField1.getText();
    Filename filename = new Filename();
    filename.setFilename(a);
    System.out.println("TextFile inserted:" + filename.getFilename());
    
    //output (ok)
    String msg = "...";
    
    
    jLabel3.setText(msg);
}
```

Comment: Your question/code is somewhat incomplete and difficult to answer directly, and you will probably want to post a valid [mre] with your question. Having said that, is the input form a JFrame? if so, it should be changed to a *modal* JDialog, and the code in main should all be called in the same thread, the event dispatch thread, meaning, the entire code within main should be enclosed within the `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {` block.

Comment: This: *"their values are static"* -- -suggests *bad* code design, and suggests that you fixed the `non-static variable count cannot be referenced from a static context` error in exactly the wrong way, the opposite way that it should be fixed. As I suggested in your previous now-deleted question, you should get most all of the code in your main method ***out*** of main and into objects proper. The main method should be used to simply create your actors (objects), connect them together, and then set them running.

Comment: Please comment back if any of this doesn't make sense. And if still stuck, then yes, create your [mre] and post it in your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for replying. I have deleted the previous question because it was closed so i thought i could not reply. Yes, it seems i have fixed the problem in the wrong way. I will follow your tip and re made everything taking out the code from the main. But honestly i'm a bit lost with SWING GUI - i approached it yesterday for the first time and there is so much, every time i search for something i get a different answer. Probably i'm gonna just follow some YT tutorial, i just hope to get the right one that talks about what i need.

Comment: The key to Swing, and for most event-driven GUI libraries, is to get out of linear thinking mode, to forget what you've learned about program logic flow from linear console programs, and instead to think in an event-driven way. Learn about listeners and how they can be used to respond to events. Create your program logic, the "model" to be OOP-compliant, so that it has state (non-static instance fields) and behavior (non-static public methods) that can be queried by or modified by the view (the GUI).